# How to get the nodes currently expanded in a TreeView control

Tags: asp.net, redirect, treeview, expand

In my **ASP.NET Web Forms** application I have a **download.aspx** page paned layout. On the left pane I have a **TreeView control** and on the right pane I display some content once the user selects a **leaf node**.

If the user (**not logged on**) clicks on a leaf node of the **TreeView** which requires authorization, the user is sent to the **login component** and, after performing the login, it is redirected to the download.aspx with the **TreeView not expanded**.

I would like to change this behavior by redirecting the user (after the login) to the download page with the **TreeView expanded** as before s/he was sent to the login component.

I didn't design the page and I never use the TreeView extensively. My first guess, since **I don't see any QueryString**, is that the node expansion is managed by a **JavaScript (or JScript) handler**, that handles the **onExpand** event of the TreeView and asynchronously fetches the sub-nodes from the database. However I am not sure it works like that.

My idea is to create a Session State object **Session["downloadTVdepth"]** where, everytime the user expand a node, somehow I store the node(s) s/he has reached. So when there is a redirection from login component to downloads.aspx, the code checks whether there is the **Session["downloadTVdepth"]** value and eventuallty expands the tree.

Is my approach correct? How can I get the info about the TreeView node(s) that are expanded? How can I launch the onExpand event without the user actually expanding a node?

Answer (score 1):

What about setting a [TreeNode.NavigateUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treenode.navigateurl.aspx) for each TreeNode, then via url you can pass custom parameter.

```
string nodeText = ...;
string nodeId = ...;
var node = new TreeNode(nodeText, nodeId) 
   {
     NavigateUrl = String.Format("~/download.aspx?CurrentId={0}", nodeId);
   };

tree.Nodes.Add(node);
```

Then in a page's `Page_Load()` you can check `Request.QueryString["CurrentId"]` value.

If you are usig built in Forms Authenticalion you might find useful `RedirectUrl` feature, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2008/01/24/anatomy-of-forms-authentication-return-url.aspx) for description with an example.

Comment: thanks! This solution seems quite interesting. However after the redirection to the login page the QueryString is not overwritten? Moreover in my TreeView I guess the expand node is managed client-side since everytime I expand the node there is not change in the URL

Comment: URL should not change while Node expand, it should be set whilst tree nodes generation.

Comment: thanks. I am now implementing your solution. However I still do not understand how it fits with the TreeNodePopulate event. Shall I fire it from page load?

Comment: I've not said anything about `TreeNodePopulate`, perhaps I missed something?

Comment: no maybe I didn't express myself clear. The treeview in the left pane controls what to display on the right pane. When I come back from the login the tree has to be repopulated as it was left before the redirect. With your solution I have the nodeId but I don't know the navigation path to get to the node (unless I explore allt he tree to find the id)

Comment: I believe you can execute Expand method for the given node, right you need to traverse the tree to expant a given node by Id

Comment: isn't it computationally expensive? I mean there is no way to get the path to get to a specific node?

Comment: I believe you can use special methods like `Find()` to find by ytext or entire node (I believe anyway it will traverse nodes)

Answer (score 1):

Treeview has onSelectedNodeChanged event you can check it out at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.selectednodechanged.aspx

Comment: thanks! I can handle this event even if the expand node is done client side?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Below, you can see my recursive version:

```
//List of storage ids of expanded nodes
List<int> expandedNodeIds = new List<int>();
//call recursive fun for our tree
CollectExpandedNodes(tree.Nodes);
//recursive fun for collect expanded node ids
private void CollectExpandedNodes(TreeListNodes nodes)
{
   foreach (TreeListNode node in nodes)
   {
      if (node.Expanded) expandedNodeIds.Add(node.Id);
      if (node.HasChildren) CollectExpandedNodes(node.Nodes);
   }
}
```